# Change dynamically name of the tab from field

Tags: reactjs

so i have 3 react component 1 is the whole dialog component, tabs component and tabsContent component.And for example in tab content i have a field that when you write something it change the tab name on what you write.. I have done that with .forceUpdate everytime when you change that field it call function from dialog component and their it have .forceUpdate.. and that field is bind with the same object like the tab name. The problem is that if i have for example like 10 fields whenever i change a field it will call that forceUpdate and i don't need to call it everytime only for 1 field.So can you give me some way to do it that ?

```
window.DialogComponent = react.createClass(
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.obj...;
    }

    onChange:function(){
        this.forceUpdate()
    }

    render:function(){
        return(
            <dialogTab obj={this.props.obj} />
            <dialogContent obj={this.props.obj} onChange={this.onChange} />    
        )
    }
)

dialogTabComponent =react.createClass(

     render:function(){
         return(
             <span>this.props.obj.name</span>    
         )
     }
)

dialogTabContent = react.createClass(
     onChange(){
         this.props.obj.name = value;
         this.props.onChange();
     }

    render:function(){
        return(
            <input text.... onChange = {this.onChange}>    
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: Please provide code examples and clearly present what you've attempted in order for us to offer help. This post is confusing :/

Comment: Its 300 lines code its too long .. and i don't need specific answer i need a direction to do it

Comment: Even if it was only 50 lines we don't want to see the whole file :) just the relevant bits to your question.

Comment: If you want a good answers, you should write a good question right? This is almost unreadable and difficult to understand.

Comment: Here i add it some pseudo code sry about all mistake..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you have a `DialogComponent` that contains two child components (`DialogTab` and `DialogContent`).

`DialogContent` contains an input that, whenever is changed, will update some value on its sibling component, `DialogTab`. So basically you have a need for [communication between sibiling components](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/#5-parent-component).

You should make use of the state in your parent component and pass props from your parent (DialogComponent) to its children, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/62767/

Good luck.